# Which ODEs have solutions in terms of elementary functions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, elementary-functions

I'm wondering what the most general results are on determining which ODEs have solutions which are expressible in terms of elementary functions and which do not. Is there some kind of ODE equivalent of the Risch algorithm?